# Изменение переменной JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript

В чужом сайте в div'е лежит числовое значение переменной, сам код в консоли хрома, получаю значение таким образом: `$('.ore').text();`

Каким образом можно среагировать на изменение значения переменной? Нужно каким-то образом постоянно обновлять значение и если оно изменится - выполнится определенный кусок кода.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите дополнение для браузера, которое будет выполнять javascript-код на странице, или используйте, например, Tampermonkey - это расширение для Google Chrome, которое позволяет внедрять на страницу свои js-скрипты. В самом коде можно использовать [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). На русском языке можно почитать, например, [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/202366/).